# Как проиграть видео с digest access authentication?

Tags: http, видео, ios

Пытаюсь проигрывать так:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kApiFirstDigitalUrl];
_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
_player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
object:_player];
[self.view addSubview:_player.view];
[_player play];
```

в myMovieFinishedCallback приходит ошибка :"You are not authorized to open this file", несмотря на то, что в строке URL необходимый хеш есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, как именно авторизоваться это в достаточно большой степени произвол того, кто писал серверную часть, так что едва ли кто-то сможет вам помочь по такому описанию - мы же фактически не знаем что именно нужно сделать чтобы сервер отдал видео (подозреваю, что он отдает 401 в HTTPResponse).

Единственное что - обратите внимание на [справку MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , там в начале есть что-то про авторизацию, возможно это как раз ваш случай

Comment: Сервер отдает это видео на комп, в андроид и т.д. 
Ссылка такого вида: http://[хеш]:@t.kraslan.ru:8000/1t2?box.
В том же андроиде не делается разницы, ссылка с авторизацией(то есть для проигрывания нужен хеш и он есть и он правильный) или нет(хеш вообще не нужен).
строка -> URI -> на проигрывание в плеер; и все работает.
Если с помощью кода, приведенного выше, запускать видео, для которого авторизация не нужна, то все ок, но если нужна, выдается эта ошибка, при том, что в url нужный хеш есть.

Comment: Справку читала и примеров много есть, но все про basic auth, то есть про авторизацию по логину и паролю, а не по хешу.
Да, сервер, скорее всего возвращает 401, но это значит, что MPMoviePlayerController не отправляет ему хеш.

Comment: Ну вот уже кое-что выяснилдось, это не хеш, это стандартный способ задать логин-пароль прямо в адресной строке, общий вид http://login:password@youUrl.com, причем пароль у вас пустой (если нужно использовать только логин, а пароль вбить потом, то : не требуется). Так что даже если вы забиваете туда некий хеш, он воспринимается как логин и естественно все проваливается. Попробуйте проделать лмбо дописать туда пароль, либо убрать :. Но реально так по http передавать не здорово - он же не шифруется

Comment: Это ведь не просто у меня "нет пароля", это стандарт в отрасли: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дайджест_аутентификация. Информация там как раз шифруется, есть другие проблемы безопасности такого способа, но не о том речь. Попробовала с настоящими логином и паролем просто запустить через распарсенный url, то же самое. А вот про то, что хеш в выражении стоит на месте логина, а пароль пустой (ну просто по форме) на этом я не акцентировала внимание. Может быть если воспользоваться таки мануалами и прикрутить авторизацию через NSURLCredential с хешем вместо логина, может и взлетит.

Comment: я знаю что такое хеш, но он обычно ставится либо в хедер http-пакета, либо как параметр гет или пост, у вас он точно не там стоит. Ну либо что-то уж очень хитрое и нестандартное на сервере накручено, такое тоже бывает. Кстати, а вебморда у этой штуки есть? МОжет там посмотреть каким-нибудь firebug'ом просто посмотреть что именно и как отправляет  браузер при запросе видео?

Comment: Ну, я имею ввиду, что хеш там точно такой же как нужно. Порешаем с тем, кто за сервер отвечает.